# VBA- Range.Find does not work after deleting hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I use the following search function, to receive the last row in my excel sheet:

```
Public Function f_Find_Last_Used_Row(wks As Worksheet) As Integer
'Finds the last used row of a sheet
    Dim rng_last_row As Range
    
   With wks
            Set rng_last_row = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                    after:=.Range("A1"), _
                                    lookat:=xlPart, _
                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
                             
    End With
             
    If rng_last_row Is Nothing Then
       f_Find_Last_Used_Row = 1
    Else
        f_Find_Last_Used_Row = rng_last_row.row
    End If
End Function
```

I need to call the function twice. First to delete all hidden rows with:

```
Set wks_in = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_one)
        
Dim r As Long, x As Long

 r = f_Find_Last_Used_Row(wks_in)
For x = r To 1 Step -1
If wks_in.Rows(x).Hidden = True Then wks_in.Rows(x).Delete
Next
```

If i call the function again with:

```
 Windows(FName).Activate
            Set wks_in = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_one)
            Set wks_out = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("one")
            wks_in.Unprotect
            wks_in.Cells.UnMerge
            last_row = f_Find_Last_Used_Row(wks_in)
```

It will return "1" as last row.
The function now just takes the fist cell in the Sheet as "rng_last_row".

But if i just call the function with the second code, without using the first call before, it works fine.

Has anyone an idea to fix this?

Comment: A side note, but that `snake_case` just looks so wrong. Also, use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: isn't this a long way to find the last row? Why not just use ```lastrow = worksheet.cells(rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row```?